# Rebound same function

Tags: jquery, live, die

I want to bind an element with a function via live() method.
The function excecutes just fine only for the first time.
I think that I have to unbind this element from any events and rebound the same function but I don't know how to do it!

Here is the code:

```
var temp = function() {
    var htmlEx = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

    $('#template_loading').fadeIn();
    $('#template_loading').queue(function() {
        $('#tp_prev').html(htmlEx);
        $('#template_container').removeClass("cur_temp");
        $('#template_container').addClass("cur_prev");
        $('#template_container').animate({"margin-left" : "0"}, 400, 'easeOutExpo');    
        $('#template_container').queue(function() {
            $('#template_loading').fadeOut();               
            $('#tp_cur').empty();               
            $('#template_container').removeClass("cur_prev");
            $('#template_container').addClass("cur_temp");  
            $('#tp_prev').empty();              
            $('#tp_cur').html(htmlEx);
            $('#tp_cur').queue(function() {
                $('#prev.pers_arrow').die();
                $('#prev.pers_arrow').live("click", temp);
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
};

$('#prev.pers_arrow').live("click", temp);
```

Comment: **That code doesn't make sense!** you remove the event and then add it again, and the callback of the function add itself as a callback. **ha?!?!**

Comment: No, you normally don't have to remove and add event listeners to run them more than once. You might have a problem with the function itself. If you elaborate on the actual problem, what you are trying to achieve, and explain what this code is supposed to do and what it does, we could help you better. Including a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the first: NEVER, EVER, EVER do like that.**

You have to cache your data and don't jump all time into the dom!!!

**second:**
in my opinion live is deprecated -so you can use ***on*** and ***off***

try that:

```
var prev=$("#prev");
var pers_arrow=".pers_arrow";
    var temp = function() {
    var htmlEx = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
    var template_loading=$('#template_loading');

    template_loading
        .fadeIn()
        .queue(function() {
            $('#tp_prev').html(htmlEx);
            var template_container=$('#template_container');
            template_container
                .removeClass("cur_temp")
                .addClass("cur_prev")
                .animate({"margin-left" : "0"}, 400, 'easeOutExpo')
                .queue(function() {
                    template_loading.fadeOut();               

                    template_container.removeClass("cur_prev").addClass("cur_temp");  
                    $('#tp_prev').empty();    
                    //you can don't use it - because .html() method already will clean container         
                    //$('#tp_cur').empty();      
                    $('#tp_cur').html(htmlEx).queue(function() {
                        prev.off("click",pers_arrow,temp).on("click",pers_arrow,temp);
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    });
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
};
prev.off("click",pers_arrow,temp).on("click",pers_arrow,temp)
```